# Conversion of CSV Files to XLSX Files using perl

Tags: perl, xlsx

I'm trying to convert CSV Files to XLSX Files using perl script. While doing so, if there is any double quotes in between the field of CSV, it is getting divided and writing into two different fields in XLSX. Could you please help me in avoiding this..?

For e.g: the field is:- I'm going to meet my fried "Richard". I need to discuss a lot with him.

Above data is divided into two fields like:

```
1st field --> I'm going to meet my fried "Richard".
2nd field --> I need to discuss a lot with him.
```

Here is code:

```
my $aoa = csv (in => $csv_file,
               encoding => "UTF-8",
               sep_char    => ',',
               quote_char  => '"',
               allow_loose_quotes => 1,
               escape_char => undef
);
```

Is there any code I can add here like allow_loose_escapes => 1 to have the entire field as one. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please post a complete script. You don't even show which CSV library you use. `use Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper $aoa` before passing it to the export library. It's unlikely that your problem is related to the quotes - if your line above is split it happens after the '.' which would be on a space...

Comment: Posted the complete script for reference. Please verify.

Comment: By complete script I meant, a complete (but minimal) self contained example program, that exhibits the problem. Your input might be something else than what you posted. Try `my $line = q| I'm going to meet my fried "Richard". I need to discuss a lot with him.,1,2|;`and use it as input `in =>\$line` then dump $aoa...

Comment: my input has 5 fields (but getting 6 fields as output):                      1000,MEXICO,LAVA,I'm going to meet my fried "Richard". I need to discuss a lot with him,COMPLETE

Comment: What do you see in the Dumper output? The line you give splits fine into 5 fields here.

Comment: If you see that the CSV parsing works correct, proceed to the next step and check your Excel file export. Instead of wrapping the whole thing in an eval, let it die where the problem is (or at least print `$@` in your error message instead of assuming a CSV related problem. `my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'excel_out.xls' ) or die "no wb\n";` could be useful in case you left the output file in place with read only permissions.

Comment: @johnroberto you have added `allow_loose_quotes  => 1`  there is a way to get this data-line parsed and leave the quotes inside the quoted field as-is. This can be achieved by setting allow_loose_quotes `1,"foo "bar" baz",42` AND making sure that the escape_char is not equal to quote_char. as Clamp mentioned CVS parsing works correct and data is divided  for `,COMPLETE`

Comment: There was a problem in CSV File itself. I corrected it by adding additional quotes,  included allow_loose_escapes => 1 and it worked. Thanks all for the help..